# link click event not firing button click event on the first try (IE only). Works on second click.

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is driving me mad.  I've got a div on my page that opens up in colorbox. When the user clicks one of the links in the div, it fires an event to the code (below) which should in turn populate the hidden field and then click a server button to run some code behind.

Problem is, in IE(9) it won't click the server button on the first attempt (yes, it does go onto the client click event). Strangely it seems to work fine in Chrome and FF.

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisID = $(this).attr('href').replace('#ca', '');
    $("#hiddenField").val(thisID );
    $("#button1").submit();
});
```

It might be worth mentioning that the links in the div that opens in colorbox is dynamically populated. But this should effect it as the click events on the links are working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that proper form would be to trigger the button submit with a `.trigger()`, not a submit.  By definition, .submit() without any additional parameters mirrors .trigger('submit') which is what you'd run on a form, not a button.

For example: `$("#button1").trigger("click");`

Here's the [documentation on `.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

To me, the more logical way to submit the form would be to bypass the button altogether and .submit() the actual form itself.  There may be reasons for why you're not doing this, but it seems more straightforward rather than relying on an element that could be "messed with" by the user.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response - been busy. I'll give this a go and get back to you. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
e=e?e:window.event;
if($.browser.msie)
{ 
  e.returnValue=false; 
  e.cancelBubble=true;
 }
else
 {e.preventDefault();}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what this is supposed to achieve? I'm not sure I get what this is doing. cheers.

Comment: You prevent event on click link  in ie this event doesn't stop to bubble and ie continue to listener first event. For ff and crrome you prevent this behavior with  e.preventDefault(); And i think match more better To use $("#button1").click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisID = $(this).attr('href').replace('#ca', '');
        $("#hiddenField").val(thisID);
        $("#button1").submit();
    }
)});
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working. Doesn't even step into the link click event now, let alone the server button. :(

Comment: This isn't going to solve the problem if the links are dynamically populated as the OP mentions.  You'd need to use .on() as the OP is attempting, as it allows the action to "bubble" through to the dynamically created dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [fiddle][1] for your answer. Its working fine on all browsers.

I don't seem any issue with your code

Just moved the code in document ready function

Comment: There's no link. Also, I think it's probably something to do with colorbox. It has never happened to me before, so I'm a bit confused.